# How to redirect to previous page and keep all filled input same using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am using php and javascript for my small project. I have a form where there are 10 or more input in one of my page. My question is When user fill the input field like textbox and textarea, and return in same page after clicking submit button if some condition is failed. How to get all input field's values

**For example**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="textfield">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield"><br/>
  <label for="textfield2">Phone</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2"><br/>
  <label for="textarea">Address</label>
  <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I like to submit it into next.php, but if any reason condition is failed and I redirect it immediately to same page having this form. I like to have all the fields filled as it is.

Comment: With the use of `session`.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" value="<?php echo $_POST['textfield'] ?>">`..@Mr.Engineer, We don not need `$_SESSION` in such cases...

Comment: Also you can use ajax for error validation check and if you need to check some condition in next.php then use session to store input values.

Comment: I have many form pages so I have a lot of input fields

Comment: @RayonDabre where is the `isset` condition?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer, This is just a _HINT_ not _ANSWER_...

Comment: But OP doesn't wants HINT.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer, _I DID NOT POST IT AS AN ANSWER_.. I am not here to spoon feed things.. My comment would definitely show correct path to the OP..And it will also make him understand the scenario..I do not think using  `session` was accurate either...

Comment: @RayonDabre But you need to be accurate with your comment also.

Comment: @RayonDabre how to redirect it? I can't get by header("Location:form.php");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery or ajax to validation (Check condition).

You need to check all conditions before redirect page to next.php
If all condition are true, then page will redirect to next.php otherwise page remain same.

### OR

You can use session in php.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="textfield">Name</label>
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['textfield_name']; ?>" name="textfield" id="textfield"><br/>
  <label for="textfield2">Phone</label>
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['textfield_phone']; ?>" name="textfield2" id="textfield2"><br/>
  <label for="textarea">Address</label>
  <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $_SESSION['textarea_address']; ?></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In next.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['textfield_name'] = $_POST['textfield_name'];
$_SESSION['textfield_phone'] = $_POST['textfield_phone'];
$_SESSION['textarea_address'] = $_POST['textarea_address'];

// Your conditions here...

redirect("prev.php"); // Redirect to form page.
?>
```

### OR

If you do not want to use session then you can pass value in url.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <label for="textfield">Name</label>
      <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['textfield_name']; ?>" name="textfield" id="textfield"><br/>
      <label for="textfield2">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['textfield_phone']; ?>" name="textfield2" id="textfield2"><br/>
      <label for="textarea">Address</label>
      <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $_GET['textarea_address']; ?></textarea><br />
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

In next.php file

```
<?php

    $textfield_name = $_POST['textfield_name'];
    $textfield_phone = $_POST['textfield_phone'];
    $textarea_address = $_POST['textarea_address'];

    // Your conditions here...

    redirect("prev.php?textfield_name=$textfield_name&textfield_phone=$textfield_phone&textarea_address=$textarea_address"); // Redirect to form page.
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sessions for this purpose. You can use $_POST array as shown below:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="textfield">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['textfield']) ? $_POST['textfield'] : ''; ?>"><br/>
  <label for="textfield2">Phone</label>
  <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['textfield2']) ? $_POST['textfield2'] : ''; ?>"><br/>
  <label for="textarea">Address</label>
  <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo isset($_POST['textarea']) ? $_POST['textarea'] : ''; ?></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I got empty value after returning to same page

Comment: You shouldn't be using redirects after an error. If you are using redirects, you need to store all values to $_SESSION and then use $_SESSION in your input field values. Post your full code.

Comment: Here you need same page in form action, then this will work.
<form action="same page where you put php code">

Comment: Removing the action attribute from form tag also will redirect it to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, others have already answered what i recommended, but if you are not comfortable with displaying through `$_POST['element'];` , you can do this by cookies too !

`When user submits form -> set cookies of data --> if user again visits the same page--> check if cookies settled --> if settled, show , else don't -- > done !!!`